# Rest assured issue io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseImpl@46fc522d in response

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

On Executing I am getting io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseImpl@46fc522d, please review the code and also see the attached postman request parameters. Please note that its content-type is multipart/form-data

```
public  static Response uploadDocument(String url, String documentType, String firstName, String lastName, String nationality, String dateExpiry, String dateIssue, String dob, String fullName, String gender, String identityNo, String middleName, String files, String files2, String token, String cookie, String xsrfToken) {
    Response response = given()
                .header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
            .config(config().multiPartConfig(multiPartConfig().defaultSubtype("mixed")))
            .header("cookie", cookie)
            .header("X-XSRF-TOKEN", xsrfToken)
    .formParam("documentType", documentType).
                    formParam("firstName", firstName).
                    formParam("lastName", lastName).
                    formParam("nationality", nationality).
                    formParam("dateExpiry", dateExpiry).
                    formParam("dateIssue", dateIssue).
                    formParam("dob", dob).
                    formParam("fullName", fullName).
                    formParam("middleName", middleName).
                    formParam("gender", gender).
                    formParam("identityNo", identityNo).
    multiPart("files",  new File(files),"application/png" ).
    multiPart("files", new File(files2),"application/png" ).
    auth().oauth2(token)
                .when().get(url)
                    .then().extract().response();
    return response;
}
```

[image: Postmain Request form-data]

Comment: Did you try System.out.println(response)?

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 i am getting " io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseImpl@46fc522d " in response

Comment: `RestAssuredResponseImpl` is just the object that holds your response information. When you print this object you will get `RestAssuredResponseImpl@46fc522d` as many java objects (not override `toString` method). If you want to print response info, use `response.prettyPrint()`.

Comment: Thanks @lucas-nguyen-17 its working by using prettyPrint()

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has already been answered in the comments, but moving it into the answers section so there can be an accepted answer.  There are two methods to transform the response object to a string for logging or printing:

`String print()`:
Print the response body and return it as string. Mainly useful for debug purposes when writing tests.
Returns:
The body as a string.

`String prettyPrint()`:
Pretty-print the response body if possible and return it as string. Mainly useful for debug purposes when writing tests. Pretty printing is possible for content-types JSON, XML and HTML.
Returns:
The body as a string.